# onSuccess(int, Header[], JSONObject) was not overriden, but callback was received

Tags: android, httphandler, androidhttpclient, asynchttpclient

I am using [android-async-http](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http), and override all the `onSuccess` and `onFailure` method, but I got the error: 
`onSuccess(int, Header[], JSONObject) was not overriden, but callback was received`.

```
cz.msebera.android.httpclient.client.HttpResponseException: Not Found
```

I just wonder I truely override this method.
Also I got the log:`onSuccess JSONObject:{"error":null,"success":false}`

```
  public static void querySecurityCode(String username) {
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("username", username);
        VStarRestClient.getClient().setEnableRedirects(true);
        VStarRestClient.post(GET_SECURITY_CODE_URL, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
                Log.i("ws", "---->>onSuccess JSONObject:" + response);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray response) {
                super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response);
                Log.i("ws", "---->>onSuccess JSONArray");
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
                super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, responseString);
                Log.i("ws", "---->>onSuccess responseString");
            }


            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, responseString, throwable);
                Log.i("ws", "---->>onFailure:" + throwable.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
                super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);
                Log.i("ws", "---->>onFailure" + throwable.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONArray errorResponse) {
                super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, throwable, errorResponse);
                Log.i("ws", "---->>onFailure" + throwable.toString());
            }


        } );
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't call `super.onFailure` and `super.onSuccess`, that warning comes from super methods when you're not overriding them.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue. My Rest API return array of JSONObjects ie JSONArray. but my code try to collect in JSONObjects.

Soluion: below code Working fine for me.
JsonHttpResponseHandler's Override method

public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, ***JSONArray response***) {
}

instead of override with below method that cause an error:
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, **JSONObject response**) {
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this lines

```
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {

System.out.println("Received event with data: " + response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> `JsonHttpResponseHandler`
>   have 2 `OnFailure` overriding methods. Try another one